# Spring MVC with Pageable parameter in controller not working

Tags: spring-mvc, pagination

I'm using Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) and my controller looks like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Foo>> getAll(@PathVariable String accountId, @PageableDefault final Pageable pageable)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or
    default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
```

Even though I have this class for configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class PageableConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: give default values  for @PageableDefault(size = 10, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC, sort = "someFieldName") may be it help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but did not work